# Close Icon in ngx-mat-select-search Is not working in a Specific Component

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I'm using ngx-mat-select-search module for being able to have a searchable select in my application. It's working properly and no errors are generated. In one of my specific components that I've rendered it in another one the "Close" icon in the aearch area is not working properly. It show "Close" instead of an icon. I've imported "NgxMatSelectSearchModule" and "MatIconModule" in the related module and also tried importing them into the module of the parent component but it didn't help.

This is an image of the outcome:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tPUo.png

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem, a work-around solution I found was to use an HTML entity with custom delete icon support that ngx-mat-select-search provides.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-select-search/v/1.7.2

`<span aria-hidden="true" class="close" ngxMatSelectSearchClear>&times;</span>`